# Converting from Military time to actual time like user's experience

Tags: javascript

I am working on the schedule for classes.  I am trying to test if the filter of time should work or not. Here's the API below. What I need to do is removing the 'h' as an hour from the api. Let's dive into the meetings where it shows start_time and end_time. I determine to convert them to the actual time excluding 'h'.

```
var filteredObject = [{
    class_number: "17002",
    subject: "COMP",
    catalog_number: "110L",
    section_number: "21",
    title: "Introduction to Algorithms and Programming Lab",
    course_id: 15268,
    description: "Prerequisites: Grade of C or better in MATH 102 103  104 105 150A or 255A or a passing score on the Math Placement Test (MPT) that satisfies prerequisites for MATH 150A or 255A . Corequisites: COMP 110. Introduction to algorithms their representation design structuring analysis and optimization. Implementation of algorithms as structured programs in a high level language. Lab: three hours per week. (Available for General Education Lifelong Learning if required by students major.)\n",
    units: "1",
    term: "Fall-2019",
    class_type: "LAB",
    enrollment_cap: 20,
    enrollment_count: 20,
    waitlist_cap: 0,
    waitlist_count: 0,
    meetings: [{
        meeting_number: 1,
        location: "JD1104",
        "start_time": "1730h",
        "end_time": "1845h",
        days: "MW"
    }],
    instructors: [{
        instructor: "bahram.zartoshty@csun.edu"
    }]
}, ];
```

So, then I added the code snippet for the convert function. Below the code for covert function:

```
//var time = "16:30:00"; // input as example
//time = time.split(':'); // convert to array

filteredObject[0].meetings[0].start_time.split(':') //convert to array
// fetch
var hours = Number(filteredObject[0]);
var minutes = Number(filteredObject[1]);
var seconds = Number(filteredObject[2]);

// calculate
var timeValue;
if (hours > 0 && hours <= 12) {
    timeValue = "" + hours;
} else if (hours > 12) {
    timeValue = "" + (hours - 12);
} else if (hours == 0) {
    timeValue = "12";
}
timeValue += minutes < 10 ? ":0" + minutes : ":" + minutes; // get minutes
timeValue += seconds < 10 ? ":0" + seconds : ":" + seconds; // get seconds
timeValue += hours >= 12 ? " P.M." : " A.M."; // get AM/PM
//show
console.log(timeValue);
```

When I run this code, it does not show the output. I do not know why it does not display from CLI which stands for command line interface. I hope you'd able to help and point out where I miss or add some function.

Comment: You do `filteredObject[0].meetings[0].start_time.split(':')` to split by `:` but your `filteredObject` has `"start_time": "1730h"` - no `:`

Comment: `split` returns a array, it does not change the variable. You need to affect the result to a new variable.

Comment: In your object the time is in the form `HHmm\h` but your code expects something in the form `HH:mm:ss`...